# How to disable the default proxy for a specific URL?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, proxy

I would like to **not use** the default proxy configured on my Windows 7 for a specific domain/URL.

The problem is that my configuration is set on "*automatically detect proxy settings*", so even if I set URL patterns to exclude, it is not used. Also, I have no control over the proxy I want to bypass.

Is there a Google Chrome plugin to avoid using the proxy for a specific URL? Or something on the system that could do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

[ProxySwitchySharp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dpplabbmogkhghncfbfdeeokoefdjegm) should work fine for you. (Note that I haven't tried it)

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I tried it, but it doesn't provide a way to set the default configuration to "automatically detect proxy settings" (as it is in the system configuration). So some LAN website don't work (I guess my proxy provides a very specific configuration), and I can't configure them all that's too much work

Comment: I looking for something that would let the system configuration be used, except for a specific website

Comment: @Matthieu do you know the AutoConfig URL being used? If so, you can set up the Auto-detect proxy settings as a default profile

Comment: I just tried it again and it doesn't seem to work at all. The system configuration is never overriden (even if I disable everything). Too bad :(